# How to find pixel coordinates of a city on a world map using longitude and latitude?

Tags: maps, coordinates

I have a world map that is 800px wide and 340px high. How can I find the position of a city like, for example, New York with latitude 40.75 and longitude -73.98? I would like to pin a marker over this point.

So far I have been adding cities manually which is problematic.

Is there any way to convert latitude and longitude values to x and y coordinates?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this image, you can see the coordinate system for latitude and longitude:

[image]

Unless you know the *exact* location (both pixel-wise and latitude and longitude) of a point on your map, you can't do anything with it. You just won't have enough information.

By *x* axis and *y* axis, do you refer to your image? What is the image of (like the whole world, or of a specific region)?

If it's of the whole world, then the coordinates would be:

- `x = image.width * (longitude + 180) / (2 * 180)`
- `y = image.height * (latitude + 180) / (2 * 180)`

Comment: I have the image of whole world. here is the link if my image. http://postimage.org/image/35ghmr2sk/

Comment: Ok, then those conversions should work. You might have to mirror along the y axis if you are drawing with the origin being at the top left corner, as my conversion uses the bottom left as the origin.

Comment: some calculations are wrong may be because of map. can you tell what is wrong. can you advice a map of width 800 which can give correct calculations.

Comment: Yep, it's the map. Look where `(0, 0)` is on the map (the bloack dot should be in the ocean, but it's in the middle of Africa): http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/6660/worldmap800.jpg

Comment: Take a look at this map projection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection

Comment: i took [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Equirectangular-projection.jpg) image from wikipedia. it also shows some incorrect calculations. Should i think more on this map and do more research or some small calculations will work. please advice.

Comment: For a different map projection, you'd have to use different equations.